# Archlinux - Autostart `screen` after boot

Tags: linux, bash, boot, arch-linux, gnu-screen

I'm building some small internet radio player using Archlinux. All I need right now is to autostart (without login!) script or just command:

```
su -c 'screen "vlc (a lot of parameters)"' vlc_user
```

By reading this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostarting and this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash#Configuration_file_sourcing_order_at_startup I have found that I need to add my command to /etc/bash.bashrc ... but this isn't working...

Can anybody help or/and guide me how to make this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't say exactly what isn't working, I infer that the program you want to start isn't actually starting on boot.

The problem is that the `bashrc` file doesn't actually run on startup - it typically runs at login. You can confirm this by logging into a user, and then the command should run. If it doesn't, however, that doesn't really matter because you should be using [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) (assuming that you're using systemd and not using init.d style scripts).

When you're system boots, systemd should have a default target, which I will designate by `$TARGET`. This target is most likely `multi-user.target`. I'm also going to assume that your command is `$COMMAND`, either a command or a script file.

Now, open the directory `/etc/systemd/system` and point your editor to the file `internet-radio.service`. Write the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Internet Radio
[Service]
ExecStart=$COMMAND
[Install]
WantedBy=$TARGET
```

This should automatically start the daemon which will start to run. There are *many* options which you can add to this file - [this blog post](http://patrakov.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html) was my main resource in composing this answer and might help you if, for example, you want to autostart the script when it dies, or have a PID file, or a million other things that systemd can do for you.